# How to add signed array to cv2 image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, opencv

I need to equalize background lighting in image. I want to create correction mask, which I will add to new picture and the lighting will be kind of equalized. This mask will obviously have negative values. How should I add it to the picture, so that the pixels don't overflow or something else. lei is the mask with values <-255,+255> , img is the acquired image <0,255>.

```
    lei = np.ones(height,width)
    lei = 150*lei-backgroundImg # bacgroundImg+lei should be uniform 150 gray image
    img = img + lei #???
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
```

Comment: Keep the image as `uint8`, make the correction mask `int16`. Add the two, the result will be `int16` as well. Now use `np.clip` to clamp the result to valid range (0-255), and `astype` to convert it back to `uint8`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `cv2.subtract` - it does the clipping automatically.

Make sure that both subtracted images are of type `np.uint8`.

Here is a code sample that compares `cv2.subtract` with NumPy subtracting an clipping:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

height, width = backgroundImg.shape[0:2]

lei = np.ones((height, width, 3), np.uint8) * 150
# lei = 150*lei-backgroundImg # bacgroundImg+lei should be uniform 150 gray image
# img = img + lei #???
img = cv2.subtract(lei, backgroundImg)
cv2.imshow('img', img)

# Reference computation:
ref_img = (np.clip(lei.astype(np.int16) - backgroundImg.astype(np.int16), 0, 255)).astype(np.uint8)
print(np.array_equal(img, ref_img))  # True - img = ref_img

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Note:
I am not sure about the correctness of the algorithm you are using for equalizing background lighting.

You should probably use multiplication instead of subtraction.
Example:

```
img = (np.clip(np.round((150.0 / np.mean(backgroundImg)) * backgroundImg.astype(float)), 0, 255)).astype(np.uint8)
print(np.mean(img))  # The mean is about 150
```